# Code optimization to make the code legit for very large input

Tags: java, optimization

I have a running code which is executing perfectly with correct output but giving "Time Exceeded" error for some input cases. This was a practice question in online coding forum. I have coded in java and used `BufferedReader`instead of `Scanner`as it is faster. Yet, I can't execute it. The question is to **perform array rotation k times towards right**. Also, the value of `n`and `k`should be space seperated. The array input should also be space seperated.

k->Number of rotation

t->Number of test cases

n->Size of the Array

Following is my code. What changes should I make so that it works for large input as well. I could have coded in C++, but I want to know the problem with this code.

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Samp  {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        try {
            InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
            int a[], b[], c[];
            int n, k;
            byte t;
            t = Byte.parseByte(br.readLine());
            while (t != 0) {
                String s = br.readLine();
                String ss[] = s.split(" ");
                n = Integer.parseInt(ss[0]);
                k = Integer.parseInt(ss[1]);
                a = new int[n];
                b = new int[n];
                String st = br.readLine();
                String stt[] = st.split(" ");
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    a[i] = Integer.parseInt(stt[i]);
                }
                while (k != 0) {
                    solve(a, k);
                    k--;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                    System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
                System.out.println();
                t--;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static void solve(int[] a, int k) {
        for (int i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            int t = a[i];
            a[i] = a[i - 1];
            a[i - 1] = t;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It starts with *ugly* formatting/indenting, which makes it much harder to figure what the code is doing. You want us to spend our time to help you, so you please spend the 30 seconds it takes to properly format your code.

Comment: Indentation is one of the problems. At least when you post for other people to review it.

Comment: Besides: **feedback** on working code should go to codereview.stackexchange.com ... but those folks expect better input as well. And side node: you **never** ever go with empty catch blocks!

Comment: Method solve is doing far more assignment operations than necessaary.

Comment: I am new so facing little problems. I formatted it again. I hope it is fine?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Then is it solve that needs to be optimized? If yes, then could you please tell me in what ways?

Comment: You still have to work on your formatting. Then the way to see what takes time is not to eyeball it or ask people, but to get it running on the worst input and interrupt it, to see what it's doing.

Comment: For a start, look at the statement `a[i-1]=t;` - you are writing to `a[i-1]` but in the very next iteration, you are overwriting that element using `a[i]=a[i-1];`, so the `a[i-1]=t;` is pointless. Think about how you could rewrite it to avoid doing this unnecessary assignment.

Comment: I know the problem. The code is correct but online judge requires it to be under certain time limit. I used `Reader` instead of `Scanner` because it is fast. Yet, the time seems to exceed. It is a practice problem that I am solving and can't seem to find apt solution.

Comment: You are using `Reader`, but also using `String.split` which is not particularly fast. Anyway, I don't think that's where the time is spent.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Thank you. So that means the problem lies in the algorithm? I had to use `split` because I had to provide space seperated input.

Comment: What is the example data input?

Comment: The issue is in fact your algorithm - although the question *might* sound like you have to use a loop for *k* shifts, it actually is faster to look for code with the *same effect*, but fewer operations. In particular, adapt your program to not loop over *k*, but call `solve` only once.

Comment: @MartinNyolt Thanks, I am now changing my approach.

Comment: @BorisShchegolev Testcases can be in the range** 0<t<20** and size of array **1<n,k<1000000** . Considering largest possible test cases and highest possible array, i get the error **"Time Exceeded"**.